# Search for empty/present arrays in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using the elasticsearch 6.5.4 and I'm trying to query for all docs in an index with an empty array on a specific field. I found the the elasticsearch has a [exists dsl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-exists-query.html) who is supposed to cover the empty array case.
The problem is: whem I query for a must exists no doc is returned and when I query for must not exists all documents are returned.
Since I can't share the actual mapping for legal reasons, this is the closest I can give you:

```
{
  "foo_production" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "foo" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bar" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query I am performing is:

```
GET foo_production/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you guys tell me where the problem is?

*Note: Upgrading the elasticsearch version is not a viable solution*

Comment: Why are you setting index = false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enable indexing for the field `bar` by setting `"index" : true`**

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are not queryable.

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html